# jquery not sending parameters to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am running into an issue where jquery is not sending parameters at all. I looped through the $_POST and $_REQUEST and neither one contained my information.

```
//jquery client side
$.post(http://www.example.com/myscript.php,{"data":"1234"})
.done(function(info){alert("returned data "+info);});

//myscript.php server side
<?php
foreach($_POST as $val){
echo $val;
}
?>
```

i have also tried $_REQUEST, I've tried $.get. I dont know what I'm doing wrong. If I call the php code in the url bar (http://www.example.com/myscript.php?data=1234) when it uses $_REQUEST it works. I tried putting the url in quotes and that didn't work, I tried taking the 1234 out of the quotes and that didn't work. I have looked through just about every jquery question on SO and didn't find something that works but I may have missed something. Any help is appreciate.

Comment: You are missing quotes around your URL for starters...

Answer (score 0):

//jquery client side

// missing quotes around url

```
$.post("http://www.example.com/myscript.php",{"data","1234"})
.done(function(info){alert("returned data "+info);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this,

```
    $.post( "http://www.example.com/myscript.php", { data: "1234"} ).done(function( info ) {
        alert("returned data "+info);
    });
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: $.post( "http://www.example.com/myscript.php", { data: "1234"} ) does not run at all. without the quotes the php script does at least return that it didn't recieve anything
EDIT: SO is shortening the url and adding that ; and i can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: it should run, I have tested my instance

Answer (score 0):

{"data","1234"}  is invaild in javascript,the right one is:

```
{"data":"1234"}
```

Comment: that was my mistake when typing it into SO. it does use : in my actual code

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest an alternative if I may...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/myscript.php',
    data: { data: "1234" },
    success: function doAfterPost() {
        // do this after the post has been sent
    }
});
```

This should send `$_POST["data"]` to the specified php file with a string value of `1234`.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue where it won't run at all with quotes around the url and then when i take the quotes away it runs and the php code returns that it received null